Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS: Remapping Alt and Caps Lock Keys (Evremap)
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Software: Evremap
I'm trying to bind Caps Lock to Esc (for VS Code) and Right Alt to Ctrl + F9 (Albert) at the system level. I've followed a guide for Evremap, doing the following:
sudo apt install git cargo pkg-config libevdev-dev
sudo dnf install git libevdev-devel

This fails with error:
Unable to detect release version (use '--releasever' to specify release version)
Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".

Continuing:
cd ~/Downloads && git clone https://github.com/wez/evremap.git && cd evremap
cargo build --release
sudo cp target/release/evremap /usr/bin/
sudo touch /etc/evremap.toml
sudo cp evremap.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable evremap.service
sudo systemctl start evremap.service
cd .. && rm -rf evremap
sudo evremap list-devices
sudo nano /etc/evremap.toml

Here is my evremap.toml:
device_name = "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"

[[remap]]
input = ["KEY_RIGHTALT"]
output = ["KEY_LEFTCTRL", "KEY_F9"]

[[remap]]
input = ["KEY_CAPSLOCK"]
output = ["KEY_ESC"]

Logging out/in does nothing. Where am I going wrong? I'd also be open to another method that remaps these keys.

The error you describe is because you followed both the (correct) instructions for installing the required packages on Ubuntu, and the (irrelevant) instructions for installing the same packages on Red Hat, which you aren't using.

Were there any other errors, or anything in the logs (look at journalctl)?

After starting the service with sudo systemctl start evremap.service, check its status to ensure there are no errors preventing it from running:
sudo systemctl status evremap.service
If there are issues with starting the service, this command will help you troubleshoot.
Also use
sudo evremap list-devices  to confirm that the targeted listed device in your .toml is indeed listed as the name of your keyboard.
